# How to create a vector of 'alpha-shapes' in matlab?

Tags: matlab

My objective is to change the parameters of different alpha-shapes in a vector, but first, I need to create this vector in a loop. However, if I write:

```
shp(1,1) = alphaShape(...); %with ... the vertices of an isosurface
```

It's okay, but in the second iteration, when it does:

```
shp(1,2) = alphaShape(...);
```

It gives me the error that `Error using alphaShape/subsasgn. Invalid arguments in indexing operation.`

I don't dive you any code because I tried separately to create a vector and it didn't work. I hope someone can help me.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: The error message implies that it is not a good idea to hide the parameters of the call to `alphaShape`.

Comment: So how do I fix it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, but you can list all the properties of the `shp` object using `properties(shp)`.

Comment: Make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cell array to store more than one object:

```
%Empty cell creation:
shp    = cell(0);

%Add new objects into your cell 
for ii = 1:2
  shp{ii} = alphaShape(...);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Indexing is not possible for object types. What could help you is constructing an Object Array. Have a look at this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html